# Magento ver. 1.8.0.0 check out time billing is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, magento, magento-1.8

http://happyshopping.jp/index.php/checkout/onepage/ here is my site when i try to checkout that time billing is not defined 
(index):773 Uncaught ReferenceError: billing is not definedonclick @ (index):773

773 line code is:
        Continue

please help me

Comment: It's a javascript error. You should debug it.

Comment: but i don't know in which file they will come i am new in magento if any other suggestions please

Comment: In developer panel it's specified the line of code where the error is coming from.

Comment: you mean error file or any other setting in admin panel..?